# GitHub Workflow: Failed to download action 'https://api.github.com/repos/workflows/checkout/zipball/0'

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, github-actions

I'm here trying to write a workflow using  **GitHub Actions** for my .net project, which is as below:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
      branches:
      - '*'
env:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
jobs:
  ci_build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - name: NPM Authentication
      uses: workflows/checkout@0
    - name: Use Node.js
      uses: workflows/setup-node@0
    - name: Nuget Command
      uses: workflows/checkout@master
    - uses: nuget/setup-nuget@v1
      with:
        nuget-api-key: ${{ secrets.NuGetAPIKey }}
    - run: nuget restore MyProject.sln
    - name: NuGet Tool Installer
      run: NuGetToolInstaller@0
    - name: NuGet Commad
      run: NuGetCommand@2
      env:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
        selectOrConfig: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: 'Build/NuGet.config'
    - name: VS Build
      run: VSBuild@1
      env:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        msbuildArgs: /p:AuthenticateWithRegistry=false
    - name: VS Test
      run: VSTest@2
      env:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
        testAssemblyVer2: '**\*test*.dll!**\*IntegrationTests.dll!**\*UiTests.dll!**\*TestAdapter.dll!**\obj\**'
    - name: Copy Files to - $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
      run: CopyFiles@2
      env:
        content: |
            **\bin\MtPtoject*.zip
            **\bin\**\$(buildConfiguration)\*.msi
        targetFolder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
        flattenFolders: true
```

But in it's execution, I'm receiving an error as mentioned below:

> 1. Current runner version: '2.163.1'
> 2. Prepare workflow directory
> 3. Prepare all required actions
> 4. Download action repository 'workflows/checkout@0'
> 5. [warning]Failed to download action 'https://api.github.com/repos/workflows/checkout/zipball/0'. Error
>      Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
> 6. [warning]Back off 29.74 seconds before retry.
> 7. [warning]Failed to download action 'https://api.github.com/repos/workflows/checkout/zipball/0'. Error
>      Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
> 8. [warning]Back off 29.102 seconds before retry.
> 9. [error]Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

1. Any guidance that what I have done wrong here **?**
2. Is there any tool that can help me to test GitHub actions without commit **?**

Comment: is `workflows/checkout` defined in your repository or are you referring to [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout)?

Comment: @smac89: no I have not defined any other workflows / actions inside my repository. Not having much idea about how this works in GitHub.

Comment: So that means you are referring to the checkout action I referenced above. In any case the version number has to match a tag in the repository of the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to an action that doesn't exist in a version that doesn't exist.  You've specified `workflows/checkout` with revision `0`, but no `workflows/checkout` repository exists.

You probably wanted `actions/checkout`, and you'd want to specify a tag, probably `v1`, so those lines would look like `uses: actions/checkout@v1`.

I'm not aware of any tools that handle the new YAML syntax for testing GitHub Actions, although there were some that handled the older HCL syntax that may have been updated to support the new syntax by now.  [This repository](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions) may have links to suitable tools.

Comment: The link you have shared is definitely not the 1 which I'm looking for. [act](https://github.com/nektos/act) is the one which could help but after installing it, not able to get it's command in CMD prompt or GitHub. Any idea on that?

Comment: As mentioned, I'm not intimately familiar with any tools thta do local testing.  You'd need to explore that are yourself.